# PDO with multiple category selection and registration

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

have a nice day
I'm using PDO, 
I want to make a multi-category selection content.
Groups of getting as follows

```
$categories= implode(",", $_POST["category"]); // 3,6,8
```

but I can not save to the database as it follows

```
id | content_id | category_id

1  | 1          | 3    
2  | 1          | 6
3  | 1          | 8
```

How do I save to the database,
thank you very much

Comment: Loop on `$_POST["category"]` and insert them in DB

Comment: How can I do with PDO?

Comment: Here you go for easy tutorial please refer to this tutorial how to use PDO [*PDO: Insert and Update Statement Use Prepared*](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html) We will not write a full code for you until you shows some of your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it true wonder? Does it work faster

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO `$table` (`content_id`,`category_id`) VALUES(:a,:b)";
            foreach($data as $item) {
            $sorgum = $db->prepare($sql);
            $sorgum->bindValue(':a', $content_id , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sorgum->bindValue(':b', $item , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sonuc=$sorgum->execute();  
            }
```